# Visualforce reportchart - can we disable access to report behind it?

Tags: visualforce, analytics, interface

Using VF I have a nice inline chart - are there anyways to make the VF page 'unclickable' so that if a user clicks on it, it won't load the report behind the chart?
So clicks on the chart do nothing? Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css

Comment: what about making an onclick event open the filtered report in a new tab/window?

Comment: In that case you would want to follow Scott's advice, except bind a click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add CSS below

```
a.analyticsCordaChart {
     pointer-events: none;
     cursor: default;
   }
```

it does the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to unbind elements.

Example:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$('a#...').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
```

I tried this out using a simple example, but beware because unbinding elements may break other behavior (as you will find if you try to <kbd>Refresh</kbd> in the following example).  Use at your own risk:

```
<apex:page>
    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oi0000005fuSS"></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

Using Chrome, right-clicking the chart and selecting `Inspect Element`, I noticed that the chart is wrapped in `<a class="analyticsCordaChart" ...`.  So I tried the following

```
<apex:page>
    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oi0000005fuSS"></analytics:reportChart>
    <apex:includeScript value="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script>
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        $('a.analyticsCordaChart').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, but this didn't stop the click through in Chrome. Chrome click on actually loads the full page in my little VF page. Poor!

Comment: You gotta find the element you want to unbind yourself and then test it to make sure you still have all the behavior you want

Comment: My example shows how to unbind an element with jQuery + some insight on how to search for HTML elements.  Much luck :)

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to hide it completely not just disable it, for a better user experience.

After trying few option with CSS below option did the trick added style tag on top of the VF Page

```
<style>
   .analyticsEmbeddedReportChart .lightning .reportFooter {
       display: none;
    }
</style>
```

You can add !important as well. adding css hierarchy will make sure only this element is hidden. This may change in future so best way to inspect the element in dev console [image]